# Piczard SimpleImageUpload not loading image

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, group-policy

I have the Piczard SimpleImageUploader in a asp.net based management tool for a product catalog that seems to work just fine for most users, but for some users, the Edit popup will show, but then the image does not load. The logo and progress will just stay there and never move. Users are typically in IE 11 on a Windows 7 PC. We have tried in other browsers, but FF and Chrome seem to not allow the popup at all, probably due to the branching of Flash, which Piczard seems to need to run.

Could there be a setting in IE that is blocking the image from uploading? The tool worked just fine for the user a few months ago, but recently has not be cooperating. I was thinking it could be a Group Policy, but I have not been able to confirm that yet.

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows updates, IE Advanced settings Reset and a reboot fixed the problem this time. I do not know which setting or update fixed the issue at this point, just that it did. I had done the reset before but that alone was not enough to fix the problem.